# Very strange crash, may related to ARC and appears on iPhone 5s only

Tags: ios, memory-management

```
Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x000000019a5639d0 objc_msgSend + 16
1  UIKit                          0x00000001915af1d0 -[UISearchDisplayController _cleanUpSearchBar] + 196
2  UIKit                          0x00000001915af0a0 -[UISearchBar willMoveToSuperview:] + 68
3  UIKit                          0x0000000191788ea4 __UIViewWillBeRemovedFromSuperview + 192
4  UIKit                          0x00000001914b83f4 -[UIView(Hierarchy) removeFromSuperview] + 72
5  UIKit                          0x00000001914bb4fc -[UIView dealloc] + 424
6  UIKit                          0x000000019159f354 -[UIScrollView dealloc] + 972
7  UIKit                          0x000000019165fc40 -[UITableView dealloc] + 1304
8  UIKit                          0x000000019159ed60 -[UIScrollView removeFromSuperview] + 80
9  UIKit                          0x00000001914bb4fc -[UIView dealloc] + 424
10 UIKit                          0x000000019165010c -[UIViewController dealloc] + 464
11 Gogobot                        0x000000010017e560 -[GBListPageViewController dealloc] (GBListPageViewController.m:288)
12 Gogobot                        0x0000000100189f84 __destroy_helper_block_982 (GBListPageViewController.m)
13 libsystem_blocks.dylib         0x000000019ab7f908 _Block_release + 256
14 libsystem_blocks.dylib         0x000000019ab7f908 _Block_release + 256
15 libsystem_blocks.dylib         0x000000019ab7f908 _Block_release + 256
16 Foundation                     0x000000018f198b78 __destroy_helper_block_165 + 28
17 libsystem_blocks.dylib         0x000000019ab7f908 _Block_release + 256
18 Foundation                     0x000000018f0a138c -[NSBlockOperation dealloc] + 68
19 libdispatch.dylib              0x000000019ab383e0 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
20 libdispatch.dylib              0x000000019ab3b56c _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 344
21 CoreFoundation                 0x000000018e5aad64 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
22 CoreFoundation                 0x000000018e5a90a4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1452
23 CoreFoundation                 0x000000018e4e9b38 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 452
24 GraphicsServices               0x0000000193f0f830 GSEventRunModal + 168
25 UIKit                          0x00000001915280e8 UIApplicationMain + 1156
26 Gogobot                        0x0000000100202c20 main (main.m:16)
27 libdyld.dylib                  0x000000019ab53aa0 start + 4
```

Here are the crash log i got from crashlytics. From this two lines, seems like something wrong with the dealloc,

```
11 Gogobot                        0x000000010017e560 -[GBListPageViewController dealloc] (GBListPageViewController.m:288)
12 Gogobot
```

but i am using ARC, and didn't even implement anything in dealloc. It never happen to me when i test, but we got the same crash report from Crashlytcis, 10-20 times a day. And some user has 30% free ram. Doesn't look like memory issue. But all the report are coming from iPhone 5s.

I have been trying to reproduce that on my iphone 5s and 5. can't recreate at all... any idea would be appreciated.

here is my dealloc in my GBListPageViewController:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]removeObserver:self name:kGBListPageVCSortSelected object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]removeObserver:self name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification object:nil];
}
```

======================================================================

New Edit:

we try to remove delegate and observers in dealloc, but seems like that didn't solve the problem. And from our crash reports, seems like all the crashes happen on iphone5s + 7.0.x OS.

here is the code we used to remove delegate, pretty simply.

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
    self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.delegate = nil;
    self.searchDisplayController.delegate = nil;
}
```

Anyone has the same issue?...

Comment: Update your question with the `dealloc` method of your `GBListPageViewController`.

Comment: @rmaddy Hi, i just update it. basically just release 2 observers, nothing more.

Comment: Even easier and less error prone is: `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];` will remove all except those `usingBlock:`.

Answer (score 1):

My bet would be on the view controller being released before the view, while the view still has a reference to the delegate and tries to call a delegate method. I've seen many of these in iOS 7.X.

Set your search bar's and search display controller's delegates to `nil` in the view controller's dealloc.

Comment: That actually makes a little bit sense, my VC is deallocated, but it still trying to [UISearchDisplayController _cleanUpSearchBar], so it crashes?

Comment: `willMoveToSuperview:` is called (with `nil` as the superview), and it seems the search display controller attempts a cleanup. Perhaps during this cleanup, it calls the delegate to tell it it has cleared some value. If this reproduces on your device or simulator, enable zombies and see. My guess, it doesn't. It's a timing issue.

Comment: the biggest problem is i can't reproduce that at all, neither on simulator nor on real devices. And i did have my zobmies enabled. But what you saying makes a lot of sense. i will try that.

Comment: Hey... Seems like removing the delegate didn't help. and based on all our crash reports, it only happens to 5s and 7.0.x OS. Very annoying...

Answer (score 1):

I've had this problem as well. My workaround was rather unorthodox; in the segue's destination view controller, I set a property to hold a pointer to the source view controller, then set it to nil in `viewWillAppear:animated`. Like I said, it's unorthodox, but it works, giving the source view controller enough time to clean up before deallocating it.

Edit:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) id vcToHoldForARCDeallocBug; 

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated { 
     [super viewDidAppear:animated]; 
     self.vcToHoldForARCDeallocBug = nil; 
} 

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {     
     self.vcToHoldForARCDeallocBug = segue.destinationViewController; 
}
```

It sets a pointer to the destination view controller when it's presented. Once the user navigates back, in viewDidAppear it clears the pointer and allows ARC to deallocate the destination view controller since everything has been cleaned up by the time viewDidAppear is called.

Comment: Hi Mike, would you post sample code for your workaround, please?